# Rails Routing and Action Logic for Searching in a Model/Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm building an app that roots to an index page where there is a form for a customer search by phone number. I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to search for a customer and how to route them in a RESTFUL way.

I need to query the customer by phone number. If the phone number is found in the Customer Model (database), it should return the customer show page. If the customer is not found, i.e. the customer is not in the database, I need to redirect to a new_customer_path, where it has a full sign up form for a new customer.

The current logic I'm using is doing a 'post' #create method for the index search form to search the database for the customer by phone number. If the customer is not found, then my route goes to the new_customer_path to create a new customer (I also need to pass the phone number they type so it automatically assigns it to the new customer, they shouldn't have to retype their phone number after the search). And here's where I use the 'post' #create method again to save the new customer. So I'm not sure if thats the right way to do it.

Question #1: On the index page, with my search form, should I be using a 'get' route to search for the customer in the Customer Model? If so how would my form look like and what action would that be? I tried using #show by using form_tag but you need to have a customer id (which I'm already searching for to begin with by phone number). Wondering if thats the right logic or if there is a cleaner, simpler logic for this?

Index page:

```
<%= form_for(Customer.new) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :phone, "Your Phone Number:" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
<%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  def create
    if @customer = Customer.find_by(phone: customer_params[:phone])
      redirect_to @customer
    else
      @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
      if @customer.save
        redirect_to @customer, notice: "Customer was successfully saved"
      else
        render 'new', notice: "Customer was unsuccessfully saved"
      end
    end
  end


  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Customer Model:

```
create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :phone
      t.string :email
      t.string :zip_code
      t.string :birthday

      t.timestamps
   end
end
```

Comment: POST verb for search is for sure broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say someone goes on index page, sees this form, enters his number and proceeds. He will instantly create new account, but he didn't mention it.

Later on, you for sure add validations for names, email, zip code, etc, at least `:presence=>true`

And then, with such logic, person enters his phone number (if he is not in db) and out of the blue gets errors that his name, email and other stuff should not be blank.

And this is just few possible ways of unexpected behavior.

That is not a way to go.

You should add some action to controller, for example:

```
def find_or_redirect
@customer = Customer.find_by(phone: params[:phone])
if @customer
redirect_to @customer
else
render :new
end
end
```

Pass params with form

```
<%= form_tag("/find_or_redirect", method: "get") do %>
 <%= text_field_tag "phone" %>
<% end %>
```

and you should provide route, in routes.rb

```
get '/find_or_redirect' => "customers#find_or_redirect"
```

This is approximate code.